# Invalid URI: A port was expected because of there is a colon (':') present but the port could not be parsed

Tags: wcf

I have just started working with wcf webservices under .net35 and I am using library http://chunktransporter.codeplex.com/ the issue i am having is when running my service hosted through iis7 i get the error:

System.UriFormatException: Invalid URI: A port was expected because of there is a colon (':') present but the port could not be parsed.

Has anyone used this library before and had similar issues? Is there something obvious i am missing?

Thanks in advance

Ismail

Comment: That is most probably some problem with the address you specified in your service or client.